# Xamarin.forms - timer works slower when phone is locked

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with timer in my Xamarin.Forms app. It is working fine when screen is on, but when I lock the phone the timer works significantly slower.

It's my code

```
        internal void StartCountdown()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource CTS = _cancellationTokenSource;

            Device.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
            {
                if (CTS.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                if (0 < Time)
                {
                    --Time;
                    return true;
                }

                try
                {
                    var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                    Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
                }
                catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            });
        }

        internal void StopCountdown()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _cancellationTokenSource, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
        }
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: Android is not a realtime OS in its app space, each OEM uses different power management settings to tune the device based upon the SoC in use and device's battery. If you really went something triggered on a time interval, you should use the OS's alarmmanager and/or use the OS's realtime clock as a reference source.

Comment: Ok, so what can I do if I want to the timer works properly when screen is off?

Comment: You should look at using a foregrounded service (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) and using the OS's realtime clock (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock) as a reference source to compare to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

I had to use BackgroundServices from Xamarin.Forms.

It is the solution, for other:

**In Android Main Activity:**

```
        void WireUpLongRunningTask()
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StartTimerTaskMessage>(this, "StartTimerTaskMessage", message => {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TimerService));
                intent.PutExtra("time", message.Time);
                StartService(intent);
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<StopTimerTaskMessage>(this, "StopTimerTaskMessage", message => {
                var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(TimerService));
                StopService(intent);
            });
        }
```

Invoke method in OnCreate();

Create Service:

```
[Service]
    public class TimerService : Service
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _cts;

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task.Run(() => {
                try
                {
                    var time = intent.GetIntExtra("time", 30);
                    var timer = new CountdownTimer();
                    timer.RunCounter(time, _cts.Token).Wait();
                    _cts.Cancel();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (_cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        var message = new CancelledMessage();
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                            () => MessagingCenter.Send(message, "CancelledMessage")
                        );
                    }
                }

            }, _cts.Token);

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }


        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (_cts != null)
            {
                _cts.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                _cts.Cancel();
            }
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
    }
```

**IN PLC library**

ViewModel with counter:

```
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<TimerMessage>(this, "TickedMessage", message => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    Time = message.Time;
                });
            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<CancelledMessage>(this, "CancelledMessage", message => {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                    Time = SelectedTime;
                    IsCounting = false;
                });
            });

        internal void StartCountdown()
        {
            var message = new StartTimerTaskMessage(Time);
            MessagingCenter.Send(message, "StartTimerTaskMessage");
        }

        internal static void StopCountdown()
        {
            var message = new StopTimerTaskMessage();
            MessagingCenter.Send(message, "StopTimerTaskMessage");
        }
```

```
    {
        public async Task RunCounter(int time, CancellationToken token)
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                for (int i = time; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (i != time)
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    var message = new TimerMessage(i);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                        MessagingCenter.Send<TimerMessage>(message, "TickedMessage");
                    });

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                            Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
                        }
                        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

And classes for messagingCenter

```
    public class StopTimerTaskMessage
    {
    }

    public class StartTimerTaskMessage
    {
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public StartTimerTaskMessage(int time)
        {
            Time = time;
        }
    }

    public class CancelledMessage
    {
    }

    public class TimerMessage
    {
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public TimerMessage(int time)
        {
            Time = time;
        }
    }
```

Comment: foreground or background service? as far as i know Android may kill the BS when screen is off but foreground will run always.